Best way to target Webkit-only browsers on iOS
Can you suggest a reliable way to detect Webkit-based (and only Webkit-based, not Chromium- or Gecko-based, as was recently unlocked due to EU ruling) browsers on Apple mobile platforms?
There is a nasty Webkit-only bug that needs to be somehow circumvented (notably: double tap with ondblclick handler doesn't work, even with touch-action: manipulation set to prevent zooming), this only occurs on Webkit and I want the main event code to be browser- or layout engine-independent to the most possible extent.

The button has different click and dblclick action handlers, different logic and this needs to be kept that way.
The element is generated dynamically by JS, as it's a part of a dialog.
The code needs to be future-proof.
Previously zooming occured but after applying the fix mentioned here I now have working click action, but not double click (two single clicks are registering instead).
All non-Webkit browsers on any device, regardless of whether mobile or desktop, mouse or touch, behave properly.

